# VS2017 preview error- You need to add a reference to Mono.Android.Export.dll

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017

my existing xamarin forms project works fine without any error using vs 2017 professional. I opened same project with VS2017 preview enterprise to use live player etc. But same project doesnt compile on it. It returns error  as

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Preview\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1789,3): error XA4210: You need to add a reference to Mono.Android.Export.dll when you use ExportAttribute or ExportFieldAttribute.
```

I am already having a reference on android project as shown below. Could it a bug in preview version? Because same project works fine in VS 2017 stable version

[image]

Comment: Visual Studio 2017 preview enterprise still have some problem, it is commended that use the  VS 2017 stable version.

Comment: @YorkShen-MSFT it used to work fine until the latest update which came out very recently. I liked Premiew indeed more,  project loads faster and build time looks like faster for xamarin forms projects